# How to convert stream type response data into an image in flutter?

Tags: flutter-image

I have to download the image in flutter from the respond data, the imgae respond data is on stream type format how can I convert this stream type data into an image

Future _saveGallery(String imagepath) async {
var data={
"key": imagepath,
};
Response response = await dio.post(
"/common-service/file-manager/v1/download-file",data: (data),
);
print(response.statusCode);
final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
quality: 60,
name: "hello");
//print(result);
}

Respond Data

�PNG   IHDR  j  �   ��NR   sRGB ���   gAMA  ���a       pHYs  t  t�fx  N�IDATx^��    �%E}?��ET��1���%�%*��D1rԠƅC0n��]����5�H��b41.D�57%*QFAa������գ����{3S���9��n�{������U�o�`�`   ��n�7    [�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   ��   �F�    4B�   �5    ��   h�@   @#j    !P   Ј�6Ps�e���Y�;���~��_-,   hӚ����[ܥ�^ڝy��/~�%����E��N;u/x��6t/y�K��k�.�������w��vZw��w;���R   ��4���O�}����������.(3b��g��*W�JY���>��~�{�Sf�<����~���s��^���wO~�����!P   l-�ԌJ��}�{_��W���m����w�9�t/|��#�8���o��T�   �zl�Ϩ���?^~"�n���/���~���7��������8�M}���=����#��>����ۮ    ���6Ps�g��8������ׯ/��I���@���<��}�ݻ}�ݷ;�䓻���-8   lQ���s�������O��^8���IOzRY6NfҼ���^��Wu�zԣ�{���嶨�}�s�W��ՅO   l~�"P�y^��nv��F7��’���5��]������o-,

Answer (score 0):

I have found out solution for this. this is the api function I have used to get the stream type response image from the backend.

```
  Future<dynamic> _saveGallery(String? imagepath) async {
var data={
  "key": imagepath,
};
Response<dynamic> response = await dio.post(
  "/common-service/file-manager/v1/download-file",data: (data),
  options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.stream),
);
print(response.data);
ResponseBody responseBody = response.data;
String savePath = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/$imagename';
await downloadFile(responseBody, savePath);
//print(result);
```

}

this the function I have used for download the response image.

```
downloadFile(ResponseBody responseBody, String savePath) async {
final completer = Completer<void>();
try {
  final file = File(savePath);
  final sink = file.openWrite();
  final stream = responseBody.stream;
  stream.listen((data) {
    sink.add(data);
  }, onDone: () async {
    await sink.flush();
    await sink.close();
    completer.complete();
  }, onError: (error) {
    completer.completeError(error);
  });
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text('File Downloading...'),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 7),
    ),
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
      content: Text('File downloaded'),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'Open',
        onPressed: () {
          OpenFilex.open(file.path);
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
   //Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>yfimageview(file)));
} catch (error) {
  completer.completeError(error);
}
return completer.future;
```

}